# Is there a way to "hack" blender to work better in windows?

Tags: performance, windows

I have been using blender for some time in a Macbook pro. Then I used it in linux. Now I'm running it in a Windows 10 machine with similar or better capacities and it doesn't render nor shows previews better. In fact it performs quite worse.

Task manager and resource monitor show Blender is not even close to maximum capacity (around 25-36% in CPU and memory usage 23 to 29% even when nothing much is running at the same time).

When I change the affinity to one processor I kind of get a faster render (not as fast as in linux or OSx).

Are there any other ways to hack windows or Blender so I can get a better performance?

Comment: It's quite normal you get better performance in Linux, as blender is basically optimized for it. As OSX is unix based it's close to linux system.

Comment: Is the problem that you want to optimize blender for your machine?

Comment: Yes, of course I want to optimize Blender for my machine :), but I don't really know if it is windows that makes Blender work slower. I'm with @Jerryno there. Maybe someone knows a way I can assign windows resources better or something.

Comment: I think the drivers provided by the manufacturer are usually the best.  I've only seen rarely that other drivers work better, and that had to do with whether to use the original Nvidia drivers for the chipset on the GPU, or the drivers that the 3rd party company providing a driver for an Nvidia chipset based GPU.  Sometimes, the chipset mfr had the best driver, and some times vice versa, the GPU card mfr depending upon the issue.  OpenGL should be standard with every Video card. Note: should be, not is, any mfr worth it's salt, will work with OpenGL or feature it and be included.

Comment: Regarding Window's resources.  The resources will be based on the type of interface the GPU uses. The latest PCIe would be best.  If you buy a GPU that uses the latest PCIe slot, and you don't have that slot, the GPU may and usually is compatible with a earlier version of PCIe but won't be able to use all the features of the GPU, and that affects performance a lot. Since you said you have a new machine, I presume that's not an issue.  You can choose whether to prioritize graphics, or math in the performance section of windows, background activity, or currently active processes.

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but you might be able to get some performance improvements if you build from source. This may not work though, and can also result in Blender being less stable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use decent video drivers that actually have good openGL performance. It's not Blender that's at fault, it's not Windows that's at fault, it's the 3rd party hardware drivers that control your hardware.

Comment: If you bought a stock machine, these rarely have superior GPU video cards.  I'm not an expert by any means on graphics processing; but, find out how many cudas your processor has.  Do a Window's performance test, and see where the system is lacking.  Often you'll find a mismatch between the math processor and graphics, even if you have a great video card.  There's some great benchmark tests that will test every facet of graphics rendering. Perhaps someone could recommend one.  I'd found one, but can't recall.  One of these will tell your where you problem is to be found.

Comment: @Cyberchipz and often if you've a laptop with dual video cards, it will default to using the Intel chipset for everything even though an AMD or NVidia chipset is also available. You actually need to go and manually install the control software from AMD or NVidia to force the machine to use those chipsets.

Comment: That's interesting, I've never seen a laptop with dual video cards.  I can see that they're often set to default to the video card on the mother board; as that's often the only one on a laptop.  So, they make video card slots on laptops, now that's interesting and could be an issue.  It can definitely be an issue on desktops for sure.  On a desktop, it can allow (but not always) a second monitor.

Comment: @Cyberchipz most mid-range to high-end laptops have an Intel chipset and an AMD or NVidia chipset as well. I've 3 of them myself (of different ages) out of 4 machines, and the 4th is a Mac...

Answer (score 0):

Try going to the task manager (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>), find blender from processes, right click on it, and set the priority to high. This will make it faster.